# Build project with Android.bp for GNU/Linux system

Tags: linux, makefile, android-build, build-system

I'm developing a command line tool which I run in *Android*; but I would also like to compile and run it stand alone on a desktop system, for instance a *Ubuntu GNU/Linux* system.

Currently it use an `Android.bp` file and is built it in *AOSP*.

**How could I build for GNU/Linux system using the Android.bp?**

I could of course just rewrite the `Android.bp` as a plain old `Makefile` but I would prefer not to create this extra layer of code to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify which target your module should be built for: **Android**, **Host**, or **Both**.
**Host** means GNU/Linux if that is what you build the AOSP in.

### Android

This is the typical binary module to be built for the device architecture.

```
cc_binary {
    name: "my-binary",
    srcs: [ "main.cpp" ],
    shared_libs: [ "libcutils" ]
}
```

### Host

There are multiple `_host` module types (e.g. `cc_binary_host`, `cc_test_host`, `java_binary_host`) that will create host binaries.

```
cc_binary_host {
    name: "my-binary-host",
    srcs: [ "main.cpp" ],
    shared_libs: [ "libcutils" ]
}
```

### Both

If you want to build both, a device binary and a host binary, you can use `host_supported: true`.

```
cc_binary {
    name: "my-binary",
    srcs: [ "main.cpp" ],
    shared_libs: [ "libcutils" ],
    host_supported: true
}
```

You might want to specify additional flags, defines, sources, etc. for `android` or `host`. You can do that with the `target` property:

```
cc_binary {
    name: "my-binary",
    srcs: [ "main.cpp" ],
    shared_libs: [ "libcutils" ],
    host_supported: true,

    target: {
        android: {
            // android specific properties
        },
        host: {
            // host-side specific properties
        }
    }
}
```

### A note on module dependencies

Every module another module depends on needs to be supported for the same target.

Example: a `cc_binary_host` cannot depend on a `cc_library` with `host_supported: false`.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer to my question, technically (kind of), however this does not solve my problem. The purpose of the linux build is primary for trouble shooting and debugging, I don't want to have it built per default of all the users and most of the time I don't want it myself either, but every now and then there is a need. - Maybe should have been more clear on that in the question.

Comment: It wont be built by default unless you add `my-binary-host` to your `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` list. Just don't and only build it using `make my-binary-host` when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

My limited experience with Android indicated that this isn't something that is easy to do. The normal solution seem to be to either generate Android files based on another build system, or parse Android files and generate files for another build system. Unfortunately I know of no existing tool that does neither for you

Comment: This is also one of those questions which are difficult to google